# How can I put an icon on the right of the action bar

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-actionbar

I want to add an icon that is used to log out, but when I include the following code the icon is displayed on the left, and I am interested in it being displayed on the right, this is my code:

```
// Icon
        supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_cerrar)
        
//listener
        supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_cerrar)
```

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                // Maneja la acción del botón en la ActionBar aquí
                // Por ejemplo, para cerrar la actividad, puedes usar:
                //finish()
                cierre()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is because you are using the home button which appears of left side. You should instead add a overflow menu which appears on right side, with `showAsAction='always'`. Refer [this tutorial here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/android-actionbar-example-tutorial)

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Pawan Harariya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16637863/pawan-harariya) said, I needed to add this code:

`menu_mail.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/cerrar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_cerrar"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Cierre Sesión"/>
</menu>
```

and

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.cerrar -> {
                cierre()
                return true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```